# Yii URLFormat Path will not work

Tags: frameworks, yii

For some reason, since I've enabled the urlManager, domain.com/site/logout/ or domain.com/logout/ will not work.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

... and here's my main.cfg

```
    'components'=>array(
       'assetManager' => array(
          'linkAssets' => true,
        ),
        'user'=>array(
           'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
         ),
         'request'=>array(
            'baseUrl' => "http://google.com"
         ),

         'urlManager'=>array(
                    'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
                    'rules'=>array(
                            'rules'=>array(
                                'post/<id:nd+>/<title:.*?>'=>'post/view',
                                'posts/<tag:.*?>'=>'post/index',
                                '<controller:nw+>/<action:nw+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    ),
            ),
```

Any ideas? Thanks :/

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis.

Comment: edited my rules. no longer using that particular rule. Apparently the only part not working now is that index.php is not being removed by .htaccess (the parenthesis were included as an example in the guide.pdf, but i removed them anyway)

Comment: What does mean 'not work'? Any error message?

Comment: I mean that I want domain.com/index.php/this/that to read domain.com/this/that instead